# Visualize stream from a PMD Camboard Nano in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, graphics, video-streaming

EDIT: honest recommendation
If you want to stream from a PMD in realtime, use C#. Any UI is simple to create and there os quite a mighty library, [MetriCam](http://www.metricam.net/) by Metrilus AG, which supports streaming for a variety of 3D-Cameras. I am able to get stable 45 fps with that.

ORIGINAL:

I've been trying to get depth information from a [PMD camboard nano](http://www.pmdtec.com/products_services/reference_design.php) and visualize it in a GUI. The Information is delivered as a 165x120 float array.

As I also want to use the Data for analysis purpose (image quality, white noise etc.), I need to grab the frames at a specific framerate. The problem is, that the SDK which PMD delivers with its camera (for MATLAB & C) only provides the possibility to grab single frames by calling

```
pmdUpdate(hnd);
```

so the framerate is dependent on how often you poll the image data.

I initially tried to do the analysis in MATLAB, but I couldn't get more than 30 fps out of the camera and adding some further code to the loop made it impossible to work with (I need at least reliable 25 fps).

I then switched to C, where I got rates of up to 70 fps, but could not visualize the data.

Then I tried it with Qt, which is based on C/C++ - it should therefore be fast polling the image data - and where I could easily include the libraries of the PMDSDK. As I am new to Qt, though, I do not know much about the UI-Elements.

So my question:
Is there any performant way to visualize a 2D-float-array on a Qt-GUI? If not, how about anything useful in Visual Studio with C++?

(I know that drawing every pixel one by one on a QGraphicsView is dumb, but I tried it, and I get a whopping framerate of .4 fps...)

Thanks for any helpful suggestions!

Jannik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QImage Class actually has a constructor that accepts a uchar pointer/array. You only need to map my float values to RGB values in uchar-format.

```
pmdGetDistances(hnd, dist, dd.img.numColumns*dd.img.numRows*sizeof(float));

uchar *imagemap = new uchar[dd.img.numColumns*dd.img.numRows*3];
int i,j;
for (i = 0; i < 165; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 120; j++){

        uchar value = (uchar)std::floor(40*dist[j*165+i]);
        if(value > 255 || value < 0){
            value = 0;
        }
        //colorscaling integrated
        imagemap[3*(j*165+i)] = floor((255-value)*(255-value)/255.0);
        imagemap[3*(j*165+i)+1] = abs(floor((value-127)/1.5));
        imagemap[3*(j*165+i)+2] = floor(value*value/255.0);
    }

}
```

The QImage can then be converted to Pixmap and displayed in the QGraphicsView. This worked for me, but the framerate seems not really stable.

```
QImage image(imagemap, 165, 120, 165*3, QImage::Format_RGB888);
QPixmap pmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));

scene->addPixmap(pmap.scaled(165,120));
ui->viewCamera->update();
```

It could be worth a try to send the Thread sleeping until the desired time is elapsed.`QThread::msleep(msec);`